# How to use Python to create a single dataset from hundreds of JSON files?

Tags: python, json, rest, csv

I am brand new to Python and REST (but a long time SAS programmer). I'm trying to download about 10 years of court files from the Wisconsin court REST API. Each case must be queried individually by case number to get the full information, and I've written a loop that gets me the full list of URL's that I need and opens each one.

I don't need all of the information in the JSON's, so I was hoping to pull out the variables that I want and flatten it into something that looks like a dataset, with one row per case and columns for the variables that I'm interested in (name, case type, charges, etc.) that I can then export into a file type that SAS can read (CSV, txt, Excel, etc.).

I know how to parse the JSON file, but I'm wondering what the best way to flatten it would be. I saw [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72458/export-list-of-values-into-csv-or-txt-file) post on exporting a CSV from a list of lists, but I would rather use a structure where I can continue to pair variable names with variables so I don't get confused (and because not all of the cases have complete information). Is there a dataset type structure in Python? If I use nested dictionaries, is there a way to export it without keys? Or is nested lists the best way to do this?

Comment: Hello! And welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, I think your question is a bit too broad to be appropriate for SO, although it is certainly not the worst first-question I've seen. It sounds like you should be interested in the data structures available in the `pandas` library. I would recommend looking into the Anaconda distribution for python, especially if you are on Windows, since it is difficult to build that math packages that `pandas` depends on. Anaconda comes with the ipython terminal and Jupyter notebooks, both of which are becoming very popular in the academic community.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "Wisconsin court REST API"?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write a custom flattener function that grabs the data you want from the json into a plain old python dict? I the data you are interested in is on the first level - the conversion will probably look like this:

```
function flattener(s):
    nested = json.loads(s)
    return { k:nested[k] for k in [ 'keys', 'you', 'need' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this data, but have you looked at using Pandas?  If you're new to Python, it's the module that creates R-like dataframe objects.  It also includes a json parser:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Once each json is loaded into a Pandas dataframe you can drop unneded columns, perform merges, and so on.